# Airflow: Dynamic SubDag creation

Tags: airflow

I have a use case where I have a list of clients. The client can be added or removed from the list, and they can have different start dates, and different initial parameters.

I want to use airflow to backfill all data for each client based on their initial start date + rerun if something fails. I am thinking about creating a SubDag for each client. Will this address my problem?

How can I dynamically create SubDags based on the client_id?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely create DAG objects dynamically:

```
def make_client_dag(parent_dag, client):
  return DAG(
    '%s.client_%s' % (parent_dag.dag_id, client.name),
    start_date = client.start_date
  )
```

You could then use that method in a SubDagOperator from your main dag:

```
for client in clients:
  SubDagOperator(
    task_id='client_%s' % client.name,
    dag=main_dag,
    subdag = make_client_dag(main_dag, client)
  )
```

This will create a subdag specific to each member of the collection `clients`, and each will run for the next invocation of the main dag.  I'm not sure if you'll get the backfill behavior you want.

Comment: Is it possible to put a pool of size 1 on the SubDagOperator so that only one client can run it's respective sub dag at a time? I've tried doing this but I'm seeing strange behavior.